# Adding another counter system in this project, wont work

Tags: java, android, button, count, imageview

right ive got one counter in this project its all working but I'm trying to put another counter at the bottom of the screen that will do the same but will work on another count. So theres gonna be two counters counting differently but i cant work out how to do it due to the app saving the data.

**xml code:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextViewCount"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:text="Count" />
```

**Main Code:**

```
package com.example.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 // Private member field to keep track of the count
 private static int mCount = 0;

private TextView countTextView;
private Button countButton;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

    /** ADD THIS METHOD **/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
      countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

      countButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mCount++;
              countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
              editor = settings.edit(); 
              editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
              editor.commit();
          }
      });
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


     }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();  
      mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
      countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why not just duplicate the code you have, but change the names of the button and the SharedPreferences value? I.e. mCount1 instead of mCount?

Comment: ive tried that it the project crashes on my phone

Comment: Post your logcat then.

Comment: And the code that you tried.

Comment: ive been told previously that copying and pasting it wont work so im trying to work out a way around doing that